# Batch file creation - Adding characters

Tags: batch-file

```
REM     @echo off

REM     ** PART1 - GET LIST OF PCS ON NETWORK **
    NET VIEW > Working\Netview.txt

REM     ** PART2 - TRIM LIST DOWN SO LEFT 20 CHARACTERS **
    BIN\sed -e 's/^\(.\{20\}\).*/\1/' Working\Netview.txt > Working\Hostnames.txt  

REM     ** PART3 - NOW TRIM DOWN TO JUST COMPUTER NAMES **
rem     BIN\fgrep -e \\ Working\Hostnames.txt  > "Working\Hostnames2.txt"
```

---

Hostnames2.txt output (Shortened, the list is alot longer)

\ALASTAIR-MUNRO
\ANDREW-GARDNER
\ANDREWATKINSON
\ANDY-KAYE
\ANDYTURNER
\BARRYWALL
\CAD-SPARE1

I need a command which i can run to then add "Psinfo -s " to each line so i get a text output similar to below:

psinfo -s \ALASTAIR-MUNRO
psinfo -s \ANDREW-GARDNER
psinfo -s \ANDREWATKINSON

Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: Since you have `sed`, something like `sed -e 's/^/psinfo -s /' working\hostnames.txt > working\getinfo.bat` should work

Answer (score 0):

to execute:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (hostnames2.txt) do psinfo -s %%a
```

or to write to a file only:

```
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (hostnames2.txt) do echo psinfo -s %%a)>output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@echo off
set input=Hostnames2.txt
set output=commands.txt
type nul>commands.txt
FOR /F %%L IN (%input%) DO (
    echo psinfo -s %%L>>%output%
)
```

If you want to execute the commands one by one instead of writing them into a file, just skip  `echo` and `>>%output%`: `psinfo -s %%L`